# Google charts numbers

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-analytics, google-visualization

i use a google charts for getting data from google analytics to see it in my website 
there is some data have a decimal number 
how to make the charts forgot the number after the decimal.

I use a php foreach in the data generate for the charts
like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ['WEEK', 'total Cost' ,{ role: 'annotation' }  ],
                <?    foreach($SOMETHING->getRows() as $row) {  
                $test = $row[2];
                $test = number_format($test,0);?>
            ["<? echo $row[0]; ?>",  <? echo $row[2]; ?>, <? echo $test; ?> ], 
                <? }?>

          ]);
```

i try the php coding "number_format" but it working in the script if i see the inspect of the page but not showing any charts in the page

if i put this code it work but the decimal is still there

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ['WEEK', 'total Cost' ,{ role: 'annotation' }  ],
                <?    foreach($tristanweekdata->getRows() as $row) {  ?>
            ["<? echo $row[0]; ?>",  <? echo $row[2]; ?>, <? echo $row[2]; ?> ], 
                <? }?>

          ]);
```

P.S.:  this code is for one of my charts but its effect all the charts and all of them not showing anything

what should i do for remove the decimal????

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your value in PHP's `floor` or `intval` method: (using `number_format` as you have it will add commas at the thousandths place in your numbers, so that should be avoided).

```
echo floor(456.8)."<br/>";
echo floor(456)."<br/>";
echo floor(456.1)."<br/>";
echo floor(456.0);

// outputs:
// 456
// 456
// 456
// 456

echo intval(456.8)."<br/>";
echo intval(456)."<br/>";
echo intval(456.1)."<br/>";
echo intval(456.0);

// outputs:
// 456
// 456
// 456
// 456
```

So in your example above:

```
$test = floor($row[2]);
//or
$test = intval($row[2]);
```

**Floor:**
*Returns the next lowest integer value*

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

**Intval**

Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the conversion (the default is base 10)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: thank you very much but i need to ask what the difference why the floor is working and the number_format not work??? @Robert Wade

Comment: Note you can also use `intval()` to do this as well. http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php  Floor may have issues with negative numbers if those come into play in your set up.

Comment: `number_format` used in the way you are using it will put a comma at the thousandths place in the number.  You're basically formatting a number for viewing with that method.  I would avoid it.  It also will take a number like '456.8' and return 457 as you have it.  View the generated source code that your PHP produces with your numbers.  It's possible you have commas in them which the Javascript is not agreeing with.

Comment: Thanks a lot now i get the idea your right my data already have commas in the google analytics data.

Comment: No problem. Just remember that number_format is really good for preparing values for display to the user in your views, however if you're needing to perform a mathematical operation on a value for further code execution, there are much better options.